# Does True Polymorph on a Simulacrum treat it as an object or a creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, simulacrum

If someone casts *true polymorph* on a simulacrum in order to polymorph it into a creature, which part of the spell is used: "creature into creature" or "object into creature"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## A simulacrum is a creature

> You shape an illusory duplicate.... **The duplicate is a creature**, partially real and formed from ice or snow, and it can take actions and **otherwise be affected as a normal creature**.

Since the spell says the duplicate is a creature, you treat it as a creature for all relevant effects, including the effects of *true polymorph*.