# If my Simulacrum possesses me via Magic Jar, to whom will my magic items attune?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, attunement, possession

I have a high level Arcana Cleric/Wizard.  Using *wish* to create a simulacrum, I can have a body double. Since I also took *magic jar*, my copy knows it, too.

I wanted to know what would happen if I ordered the simulacrum to possess me. Specifically, if I am attuned to the following magic items, will my body double inherit my attunement and thus gain the items' benefits?

- Headband of Intellect
- Robe of the Archmagi
- Wand of the War Mage

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site.

Comment: As an asside, this may not work in the first place, since _magic jar_ needs the user's soul: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115682/does-a-simulacrum-have-a-soul

Comment: @TheLittlePeace Simulacra are creatures too, so they seem to meet all requirements of casting the spell. RAW doesnt look like it takes a hardline stance either way.

Answer (score 9):

## RAW uncertain, RAI no attunement transfer

Whether or not it is your *[Simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum)* double or another creature possessing you is irrelevant, as a *Simulacrum* is not you, but rather "an illusory duplicate" per the spell description. So you couldn't just hand over your items and have them already be attuned, or have a spell that targets self also target them.

So that leaves the more broad question of whether or not item attunement is inherited via *[Magic Jar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar)* possession. The spell says your stats (aside Intelligence, Wisdom and Charisma) are replaced by the creature's, and you retain your alignment and class features without gaining theirs, but it speaks nothing to attunement.

Reading the rules on [attunement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement), we see that attuned items are attuned to a "creature", but as with anything related to *Magic jar*, the definition of creature becomes a bit vague here. Is it the body or the mind? The use of both "creature's body" and "creature's soul" in the text seems to imply that it's a bit of both.

As far as I can tell there is no defining answer given in any of the source books to clear this up, which means it'd be purely up to the DM's interpretation as to whether or not attunement transfers. It is worth mentioning however, that while not an official ruling, [one of the co-creators of D&D 5e has offered their input on this exact topic](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/02/10/are-attuned-items-attuned-to-the-mind-or-the-body-of-the-character/), to which they ruled that attunement is to the mind and not the body.

In summary, RAW is silent on the matter, while RAI seems to be that they would not inherit the attuned items.